# Does using one attribute of configChanges calls onConfigurationChanged() anyway?

Tags: android, android-configchanges

If I use this code in my Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MyAct"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> //<-SEE THIS
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

As you can see I am declaring that the activity shall not be restarted when the screen rotation and keyboard visibility have been changed.

However, does this mean that the method `onConfigurationChanged()` will be called ONLY in case of these two events (in other cases the activity shall restart)?

Or it means that the activity does not restart even if only one attribute has been used?

I haven't been able to find this answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. It means that the activity does not restart even if only one attribute has been used. The `onConfigurationChanged()` method will be envoked if one of the attribute occur, i.e for those which are not specified, the activity will restart when they occur.